# Looper leaking Messages

Tags: java, android, multithreading, memory-leaks

So I have this looper that I use to perform long running tasks.
I pass it `Worker` objects which is essentially a wrapper around a Runnable

I've noticed that it seems to be leaking Message objects which are all the exactly the same size

Any ideas why this might be happening?

The thread:

```
public class WorkerQueue extends Thread {
  public Handler handler;
  int priority = Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 1;
  private static WorkerQueue self = null;

  public static WorkerQueue getInstance() {
    if (self == null) {
      self = new WorkerQueue();
      self.start();
      self.setPriority(priority);
    }

    return self;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();
      handler = new Handler();
      handler.getLooper().getThread().setPriority(priority);
      Looper.loop();    
  }

  public synchronized void enqueueTask(final Worker task) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          task.run();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the android documentation, you should use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for this.

You can do it like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); //or whatever you think is best, read the Javadocs for the different options under Executors
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //implement long running task here
    }
});
```

It shouldn't be difficult to have your current Worker class implement Runnable, then you can pass them directly to the execute method.

Of course, you can always rewrite Java's ExecutorService if you want (that's what you seem to be doing), but it's unlikely you'll be better off in the end.

Comment: Hmmm the reason I went with a Looper is because I can choose to enqueue a task to the front of the queue. Is there a way I can do this with a ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: Hmmm, well, if you look at [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for it, there is a method that allows you to access the queue, but "Method getQueue() allows access to the work queue for purposes of monitoring and debugging. Use of this method for any other purpose is strongly discouraged." The whole point of the cachedThreadPool is that it begins all tasks you set it as soon as it can (it's not single threaded), creating new threads or reusing old ones as needed. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor lets you schedule tasks.